# Marijuana Across State Lines, where State Laws Differ

Tags: united-states, colorado, medical-marijuana, new-mexico, drugs

I'm taking a trip to Colorado, where recreational marijuana is legal. I live in New Mexico, where I have my state certified, state legal medical marijuana card. I'm taking a plane to and from.

Can I buy marijuana in Colorado, and take it on a flight back to New Mexico, with the above legal, certified restrictions/allowances?

Answer (score 6):

Leaving Colorado with a Marijuana product is illegal. You cannot bring Marijuana to Denver International or any other airport in Colorado. You also cannot bring Marijuana into a Federal Park, reserve, ski slope or National Parks.

[Colorado has a site outlining these restrictions](https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/marijuana/driving-and-traveling), so no, you cannot bring back Marijuana to your home state, even if you can legally possess it in that state.

Comment: The state's claim is highly unsatisfactory, because it does not give any statutory basis for claiming that transporting legal marijuana across state lines is illegal. Can you do better than them? I don't see any basis for that in Colorado law.

Comment: @user6726 It isn't Colorado law though, its Federal law. National Parks are owned by the Federal Government, Denver International is a port-of-entry. Transfer between States is regulated by the Federal government. Marijuana is still illegal by Federal standards.

Comment: By the same law, it is illegal to possess marijuana in Colorado. There is no law against interstate transport that does not also criminalize intra-state transport -- they don't mention that the whole system is predicated on a wink and nod system.

Comment: @user6726 Of course it is, which is why it works when dealing with officers of the state. When you move to dealing with Federal officers (TSA, Border Patrol, Park Officials, etc) they have to play by Federal rules, and charge under Federal crimes, which is why they say "don't bring it here".